# iOS 9 Facebook permissions failing

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login, ios9

I am using Xcode 7 beta 6, iOS 9 beta 5.
In my existing code (which works in iOS 7 & 8) I have this:

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

        [login logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"manage_pages"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"There was an error with FB:\n %@",error.description);
            } else if (result.isCancelled) {

            } else {
                if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"manage_pages"]) {
                    NSLog(@"permissions granted! %@",[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]permissions]);
                    // Do work
                    [self facebookInfo];
                }else{
                    NSLog(@"permissions NOT granted");
                }
            }
        }];
```

As soon as the application switches over to either the Facebook app or Safari, the handler throws the error

```
There was an error with FB:
 Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.login Code=301 "(null)"
```

On the device, the permission page is shown in Safari and once you agree to the permissions you are prompted about Safari wanting to open my app back up. Once the application reopens nothing happens, which makes sense considering that the handler has already failed.
Can anyone shed any light on this? I'm struggling to find any other examples of this.
Thanks a lot,
Luke

Comment: Check whether you are calling method to fb-login more than once anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolution to this issue was that the facebook SDK appears to be buggy.
After downgrading my project pod files to:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.2.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.1.0'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.1.0'
```

I found that this error went away and normal operation was resumed.
This appears to be a bit of a widely-found bug that has started cropping up on other SO questions.

Comment: Have you been able to find another way to solve it? Same issue for me with 4.6 on xCode's simulator with iPhone (iOS8).

Comment: @mylogon I am getting the same issue and I think just downgrading sdk won't solve it. Did you get any other solution ?

Comment: I've not returned to this project yet. When I left it, this did work. As said by Chris pan, it's not advisable to use different versions, so I will be fixing this when I do return to it. Try this method, but set them all to either 4.1.0 or 4.2.0. It should help (no promises)

Comment: Latest documentation from FB says 'This is an Xcode warning indicating the the canOpenURL: call returned false. As long as you have configured the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes entry in your plist as described above, you can ignore this warning' [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9)

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons, iOS 9 requires apps to white list apps they allow to open. See the section "Whitelist Facebook Apps" on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Comment: I added the Facebook app to the whitelist, but not the other ones. I will try this later on. Thanks.

Comment: Just to confirm, adding these did not resolve the issue. It is still failing at the handler when either switching to Facebook (app) or Safari (with no app installed)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try again with 4.6 of the SDK, and using the GM seeds of iOS 9 and Xcode 7? If there's still a problem, it'd be great if you could file a report to developers.facebook.com/bugs for us to help debug. Thanks!

(P.S. you should generally avoid using different versions of the kits in your Podfile)

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem. Then I followed this link step by step https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9.
Downloaded the recent sdk & got all required datas.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the login button which I had created using `FBSDKLoginButton`. I changed `FBSDKLoginButton` to `UIButton`. This worked for me.